# Apache2 "Deny from all" directive in 'security' section stops access in Virtual Host sections

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have the following two sections in my agache2.conf file.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/bernie/development/public2"
ServerName myfl2.local
  <Directory /home/aaaa/development/public2>
    AllowOverride None
    #Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The following file exists with some content:

```
/home/bernie/development/public2/a/a/index.html
```

For some reason, trying to access

```
myfl2.local/a/a/index.html
```

I get a "403 Forbidden" error. I've narrowed the problem down to the line "Deny from all" in the first directory section above, but I can't figure out how to keep that (as it's a very important directive) and allow access to public2/a/a directory. Anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that I can think of. One is to create a separate directory directive. The other is to do the following:

Above the directory directive:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/public2/a/a/*" publicaccess
```

Within the directory directive:

```
Allow from env=publicaccess
```

Although, I'm curious: what's the point of a directory that's only Deny all?

Comment: I've seen a lot of sites where `<Directory />` is `Deny from all` and then specific directories are overridden to allow access -- Not sure how much extra security it buys, but it's an option :)

Comment: I could see that. I'm not saying it's wrong, just that I was curious about the reasoning :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `Order` setting is the key here.  The `/home/aaaa/development/public2` directory has both an `Allow from all` and `Deny from all` directive associated, and the `Order` is set to `allow,deny`.  This means that a deny command is always going to take precedence over an allow command.

Changing the `Order` directive in the more specific block should solve the problem.  Another option would be to take out the explicit `Deny from all` in the block for `/`; when the order is `allow,deny` then no request will be allowed without an explicit `Allow`.